# Make jQuery Ajax Call on Master Page?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, web-services, master-pages

Am I missing something?  I'm trying to do a simple ajax call using jquery to a web service on my site and I get a 500 error every time when I make the call from the master page.  Has no one ever made an ajax call from a master page or am I just crazy and extremely deprived of sleep?

Example:

### MasterPage.master

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" });

        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Services/Test.asmx/HelloWorld") %>',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

### /Services/Test.asmx

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
   Return "Hello World"
End Function
```

See anything wrong?  Do I have a misunderstanding of the Master Page? Please help!

Comment: There is nothing specific to a MasterPage that would cause this. Are you saying it works when you're code is in a view page rather than master page?

Comment: Are you also getting a 500 error when you load `~/Services/Test.asmx/HelloWorld` in your browser?

Comment: Try checking the IIS logs etc.

Comment: I'm able to "browse" to my webservice page (~/Services/Test.asmx/HelloWorld) and it loads fine.  The method is available and I'm able to invoke it.  About to verify that I am able to view the web service on a content view page.

Comment: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/HelloWorld'. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/HelloWorld'. Source Error: [InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/HelloWorld'.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I believe I have figured out the problem.  Now I'm beginning to think I am just sleepy.  A couple of issues that I had and I'll list them for everyone else to make sure they DON'T do in the future:

**1) I remember reading another post previously that explained that an ajax call via the jQuery library does not like a null object for data so something has to be listed even if it's an empty array.  So, that's exactly what I added:**

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: 'POST',
            data: [],
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Test.asmx/HelloWorld") %>',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                //alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                //alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                $('#ajaxResponse').html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

**2) Once I got past the jQuery ajax problem, I was then presented an error message from the web service itself.  Warned me that to be able to call the web service from a script, I have to add the following line:**

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Test
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "[{""Hello World""}]"
    End Function

End Class
```

This solved it and now I can call it wherever it resides.  Thanks for the posts but looks like I was just overlooking things as usual...